# Android studio Fragment view as a parameter?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm writing an application and i have a certain function, which takes view: View as a parameter:

```
private fun closeKeyboard(view: View) {
    val imm = view.context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
}
```

The entire aplication is written with fragments. This function is meant to hide the keyboard, when submit button is clicked. However, i don't know how to pass Fragment's view as a parameter when i try to use the function:

```
private fun onSubmitNumber(){
    val userNumber = binding?.textInputEditText?.text.toString()

    closeKeyboard()
```

How to get a View type parameter from a fragment?

Comment: You could just use the root view from your binding class there - `binding?.root`

Comment: Or, [call `getView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment?hl=en#getView()).

Comment: or since it's Kotlin, `getView()` can be referenced as a property called `view`. So you can just call `closeKeyboard(view)`! The way that function works, it's really just getting a `Context` from the `View`, and also a reference to the `Window` the View is in - so really you can pass in any View on the screen that you have access to. You could use your `textInputEditText` if you wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use any view in your fragment:

```
private fun onSubmitNumber(){
    val userNumber = binding?.textInputEditText?.text.toString()
    closeKeyboard(binding?.root)
}
```